# Error 404 on Apache when the URL contains characters like brackets or hyphens

Tags: apache, url, http-status-code-404, zend-framework2, url-routing

In my Zend Framework 2 application I have a catalog of cities with links to sports pages:

page "Cities" (`/catalog`)

> Madrid **link**: `website.tld/catalog/Madrid`
>
> Berlin **link**: `website.tld/catalog/Berlin`
>
> London **link**: `website.tld/catalog/London`

page "Sports in London" (`/catalog/London`)

> Foo **link**: `website.tld/catalog/London/Foo`
>
> Bar (Bar) **link**: `website.tld/catalog/London/Bar (Bar)`
>
> Baz - Baz **link**: `website.tld/catalog/London/Baz - Baz`

The URLs are escaped and work well on my virtual machine (nginx). But not on the (Apache) server. There I'm getting a `404 Error`, when a URL contains a bracket (e.g. `Bar (Bar)`) or a hyphen (e.g. `Baz - Baz`).

How to fix it?

(I think, that it's not a ZF2 issue. But since I cannot be sure, I'm tagging this question with the `zend-framework2` tag too.)

---

EDIT:

I found the bug. It's nothing about Apache, but my own bad. I defined the route in my ZF2 module config wrongly:

```
'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[\p{L}\p{Zs}]*)/(?<sport>[\p{L}\p{Zs}]*)'`
```

instead of something like this

```
'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[\p{L}\p{Zs}]*)/(?<sport>[\p{L}\p{Zs}\p{P}]*)'`
```

(See also "the list of the [general category property codes are supported](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/pcre/pcrepattern.html#SEC4)" by [PCRE](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/pcre/index.html))

Comment: Check your error log to see if Apache tells you anything usefull there!

Comment: Seek and you shall find. Do you possibly use mod_security in Apache? [Link here!](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/08/securing-apache-part-10-mod_security/) seems it doesn't like hyphens etc.

Comment: Thank you for your respose. The error log tells us nothing. And in the access log only contains an info, that a 404 error has occured: `"GET /catalog/Berlin/Akrobatik%2C%20Sportakrobatik HTTP/1.1" 404 2251 "http://website.tld/catalog/Berlin" "client info ..."`

Comment: What absout mod_security? Is it on?

Comment: No, mod_security is not in the list of the loaded modules.

Comment: I found the bug. It's nothing about Apache, but my own bad. I defined the route in my ZF2 module config wrongly: `'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[\p{L}\p{Zs}]*)/(?<sport>[\p{L}\p{Zs}]*)'`! Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: Regexp is the root of (almost) all evil!